# How to override parent style when extending a polymer element

Tags: css, polymer

I have one element that extends another and I'm having trouble getting the styling to override the parent using [the example](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#extending-other-elements) in the documentation. For example, say I want to style the praise in the parent element:

```
<polymer-element name="polymer-cool">
  <template>
    <style>
        :host #p {
            color: red;
        }    
    </style>
    You are <span id='p'>{{praise}}</span> <content></content>!
  </template>
  ...
</polymer-element>
```

but change that in an extension of that element:

```
<polymer-element name="polymer-cooler" extends="polymer-cool">
  <template>
    <!-- A shadow element render's the extended
         element's shadow dom here. -->
    <style>
        #p {
            color: blue;
        }
    </style>
    <shadow></shadow> <!-- "You are cool Matt" -->
  </template>
  ...
</polymer-element>
```

You can see in the JSfiddle below, that I haven't been able to change the color of the span#p. I've tried a few other things like

```
polymer-cooler #p {
    color: blue;
}
```

And tried putting the style inside of the  tags, but no luck. Hoping it's possible and I'm just missing something.

http://jsfiddle.net/jamstooks/tpyL9/

Answer (score 4):

Well, this looks like this works. I'd love to get some clarification from someone on whether this is the best way to do this:

```
<polymer-element name="polymer-cooler" extends="polymer-cool">
  <template>
    <style>
         {
            :host::shadow #p
            color: blue;
        }
    </style>  
    <shadow></shadow>
  </template>
  ...
</polymer-element>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jamstooks/tpyL9/4/

**EDIT: 7/22/14**

Per the comment from Scott below, I have updated the code above from `:host /deep/ #p` to `:host::shadow #p`

Comment: `:host::shadow #p` is the preferred syntax. `/deep/` will penetrate sub-element shadow-dom, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: Thanks, Scott. Yes, that's definitely not what I want and makes more sense.